# What exactly does '3.4E +/- 38 (7 digits)' mean?

Tags: c++, math, numbers

I'm trying to understand the range of data types. For non-floating point numbers it's easy enough, but then for float and double the ranges are listed as:

float: 3.4E +/- 38 (7 digits)

double: 1.7E +/- 308 (15 digits)

But in layman, what exactly does that mean, and how can I make use of that information?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6273/what-does-e-mean-in-9-0122222900391e-5

Comment: Perhaps you should read about [IEEE floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)

Comment: ```1.7E3 means 1.7 x 10^3  = 170 ---
1.7E-3 means 1.7 x 10^-3 = -170```
so mEe is m x 10^e

Answer (score 8):

The

```
3.4E +/- 38
```

means that:

- the largest positive value that a `float` can represent is about 3.4e38;
- the smallest positive value is about 3.4e-38.

Similarly, the range of negative values is from -3.4e38 to about -3.4e-38.

Here, `MeE` denotes `M` multiplied by 10 to the `E`'th power.

The

```
(7 digits)
```

means that a `float` can represent approximately seven significant decimal digits.

The reason of these values are approximate is that they are exact *in binary*, and there's a fractional number of decimal digits for each binary digits.

Comment: Does "3.4E-38" mean "3.4 x 10^-38"  ? - Thanks

Answer (score 2):

float: Range is from `3.4E-38` to `3.4E38` (positive or negative), with 7 significant digits of precision.

double: Range is from `1.7E-308` to `1.7E308` (positive or negative), with 15 significant digits of precision.

They also include 0.

`mEe` is computer notation for `m` times 10 to the `e` power.

Comment: Does "3.4E-38" mean "3.4 x 10^-38" ? - Thanks

Comment: @Job_September_2020 Yes. In scientific notation, `nEy` means `n * 10^y`